# Typescript: this.property inside a function gives error of type implicitly any. Can't call new Object();

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to integrate typescript into my learning path and understanding the differences with javascript.

So far I was able to resolve all issues but I got stuck on something that appears pretty basic.

```js
function Person() {
    // ERROR: this implicitly has type any because it does not have a type annotation
    this.name = 'brad';
}

// ERROR: new expression, whose target lacks a construct signature, implicitly has an any type
const brad = new Person();

console.log( brad );
```

I tried some possible solutions:

- disabled no implicit this in tsconfig:

  > this would work in removing the first error, but the one on the `new Person()` remains
- set this: any in the parameter parenthesis (with noimplicitthis to true)

  > ```js
  > function Person( this: any ) { // ERROR: unexpected any. specify a different type
  > ```
- tried to use an arrow function to store it
- tried using constructor inside the Person function

Had a look at the official typescript handbook but I just don't seem to find anything that correlates with my current problem.

Why does the above code work in JS while in typescript I can't seem to make it work?

Comment: `name` is not declared. You should create a Person class with a name field instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript is complaining here that it doesn't know at declaration what is the type of `this` and what it should return

We can solve this in 2 ways -

**Solution 1: (Preferred)**

```
// Convert this constructor function to Person

class Person {
    name = 'brad'
}

const brad = new Person();

console.log( brad );
```

**Solution 2: (Hacky)**

```
interface Person1 {
    name: string
    // All properties of Person goes here
}

const  Person1 = function (this: Person1){
    this.name = 'brad'
} as any as { new (): Person1 }

const foo = new Person1();

console.log(foo);
```

[Code Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTC84iAIGUHsA2BXALgSzgOygRkvg8EAKGJCgGEsA3AUwCcUoUALNAZygGMt2V6kXFHHpQAZkkxCM2YVAAKDdllJcEAQ3adF9ZdgDexKMaiZ1AW1pRQUAOQAjeuoAmt4gF9VvJo5fXTtADuCkpYABQAlADcXpjKCLQAdAhwAOZhUL7OUNGkZGCENvDI6FhQAEyFVSTEaJgoDGLqXFY6ejhQhiamFrQAXFB89HWpRibkAIIICFAADvRwswzotJxwYiG6Zalwq1AsDLQesXzGbVgdNhJSpdhhrBwD55g4EV0mD%20yJZpb%20Dk6uDxQTTAzAAT2BnH0AWCkSeoReUE8xB4cSYYjgcH8mCCm3akRiKN4iCSKXS4kxuSAA)

Comment: thanks, I think i'm wrapping my head around it now.

Comment: @gipo355  If it answers your question, you can mark it as accepted answer else let me know what am I missing?